# "Interaction technologies" vs. "interactive technologies"

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives

What is your feeling about the differences between the two?

Comment: I would say that the first option refers to technologies that facilitate interaction while the second refers to technologies that  have the ability to interact with humans or other technologies.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at Computer Science syllabi that cover these subjects - both are often mentioned.  The phrase "Interaction Technologies" tends to be a more all-encompassing subject and more of general overview of the technologies involved with human computer interaction (HCI).  The phrase "Interactive technologies" tends to concentrate on the individual technologies themselves and how they work.  So essentially the second is a subset of the first.